# A conjecture about primes and holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, conjectures, holomorphic-functions

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897785/a-conjecture-about-integer-polynomials-and-primes) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897785/a-conjecture-about-integer-polynomials-and-primes/1897838#1897838) I raise the following conjecture:

> If $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ is a set of entire holomorphic functions and if
>   for every $m\in\mathbb N$, it exists a function with $f_i(m)\in\mathbb P$, then some function $f_k$ is a constant.

Can this be proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Set $f(x)=2\cos^2(\pi x)$. This is an entire function that is prime at every natural number.